# How to display only some widgets of a sidebar?

Tags: theme-development, widgets, sidebar

I would like to break up a sidebar over three containers. Each container should hold up to three widgets of the sidebar. Therefore, I need to find the HTML for only the widgets 0 to 2, 3 to 5 and 6 to 8 separately.

Normally, I would use `dynamic_sidebar()` to display the sidebar, but this function doesn't accept parameters to specify that I only want a range of the widgets of the sidebar. Moreover, I found  `wp_get_sidebars_widgets()`, but it is not intended to use for themes.

How can I get only the widgets in a given range of a dynamic sidebar? For example, this is what I think of.

```
// functions.php
// display range of widgets of a sidebar
function dynamic_sidebar_range($name, $from, $to)
{
    $widgets = get_dynamic_sidebar($name); // this function doesn't exist!
    for ($i = $from; $i < count($widgets) && $i < $to; ++$i ) {
        $widget = $widgets[$i];
        echo $widget['before_widget']
           . $widget['before_title']
           . $widget['title']
           . $widget['after_title']
           . $widget['content']
           . $widget['after_widget'];
    }
}
```

```
// frontpage.php
// consists of blocks of three posts or widgets alternatingly
for ($sections = 0; $sections < 3; ++$sections) {
    // display three posts
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3 && have_posts(); ++$i) {
        the_post();
        // ...
    }
    // display three widgets
    $from = $sections * 3;
    $to = $from + 3;
    dynamic_sidebar_range('name', $from, $to);
}
```

Comment: Display based on what? Try conditional tags. Please try and be more specific with your question as its currently far too broad.

Comment: @BradDalton I want to display the first three widgets of a given dynamic sidebar in one HTML container, the next three widgets in another, and so on. I added a code example to make it more clear.

Comment: Silly question: why not just register **three sidebars**?

Comment: @ChipBennett I considered that, but I am interested of how I could split the widgets automatically.

Comment: Seems like overkill to me. Much easier just to register 3 sidebars, and then instruct users to add 1-3 Widgets to each one.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is "to break up a sidebar over three containers", then you don't really need to rebuild `dynamic_sidebar()` to do it. There is a filter called `dynamic_sidebar_params` that can be leveraged to break up the sidebar.

```
function add_closing($params) {
  $params[0]['after_widget'] = $params[0]['after_widget'].'</div><!-- close wrapper-thing -->';
  return $params;
}

add_filter(
  'dynamic_sidebar_params',
  function ($params) {
    static $c = 0;

    if (0 === $c || 0 === $c%3) {
      $params[0]['before_widget'] = '<div class="wrapper-thing" style="border:1px solid white;float:left">'.$params[0]['before_widget'];
      remove_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params','add_closing');
    } else {
      add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params','add_closing');
    }

    $c++;
    return $params;
  }
);
```

I found this interesting in a "code golf" sort of way. I am fairly sure that three distinct sidebars, as suggested in comments, is a better way to do this.

This will wrap the widgets in a sidebar in distinct containers, three per container. If you want distinct widget areas what you are doing is entirely the wrong to go about things. It is going to be more confusing than having individual sidebars and it will remove control from the end user. That is not to mention that you will need to largely recreate Core code.

Just use the sidebar system as it was intended.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if I understand it entirely though. Does this just add container tags every three widgets? I need to break it up into containers that are at different locations in the HTML structure. But if there is a way to do this by hooking into Wordpress events, that would be fine.

Comment: @danijar : see the edit